# Firefox flexbox not working

Tags: html, css, firefox, flexbox

I've made code, it's a bubble menu with a button. It works perfectly on Chrome but it works wrong on mozilla.
You can see and try it

```js
$(".roundedBallOuter").click(function(e) {
  $(this).toggleClass("clicked");
});
```

```css
body {
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
.roundedBallOuter {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.roundedBall {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #ccc;
  border-radius: 100%;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.roundedBall:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.1);
  -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px #555;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
.subBall {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #0077ab;
  border-radius: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  z-index: -1;
}
.roundedBallOuter.clicked .subBall.linkedIn {
  transform: translate(-10em);
  -webkit-transform: translate(-10em);
  -moz-transform: translate(-10em);
  -ms-transform: translate(-10em);
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
.roundedBallOuter.clicked .subBall.facebook {
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-10em) rotate(-45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-10em) rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-10em) rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-10em) rotate(-45deg);
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
.roundedBallOuter.clicked .subBall.twitter {
  transform: rotate(90deg) translate(-10em) rotate(-90deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg) translate(-10em) rotate(-90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(90deg) translate(-10em) rotate(-90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg) translate(-10em) rotate(-90deg);
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
.more {
  font-size: 20px;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}
.more>span {
  color: #0077ab;
  display: block;
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 25px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="roundedBallOuter">
  <div class="roundedBall">
    <span class="more"><span>Click</span> for more information</span>
  </div>
  <div class="linkedIn subBall"></div>
  <div class="facebook subBall"></div>
  <div class="twitter subBall"></div>
</div>
```

Could you please help me, fix this bug?
Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm on Firefox 48.0.2 64 bit and the small blue circle jumps from the top to the side when I click it

Comment: try to enter from chrome. It works as I want it to work. Something's wring with flex I think...

Comment: @Tinakicious three of the `flexbox` containers are `absolute` and that is why it is showing unpredictable behaviour... AFAIK  you should change that... Using `align-items: stretch` solves problem in Firefox but you will face issues in the long run I guess unless you correct the design...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You positioned the small balls as `absolute`, however you didn't give the the absolute position.

You can fix that by setting that position to the exact position chrome put the originally (which is `top: 75px; left: 75px;`)

Here is the fix:

```js
$(".roundedBallOuter").click(function(e) {
  $(this).toggleClass("clicked");
});
```

```css
body {
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
.roundedBallOuter {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.roundedBall {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #ccc;
  border-radius: 100%;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.roundedBall:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.1);
  -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px #555;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
.subBall {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #0077ab;
  border-radius: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 75px;
  left: 75px;
}
.roundedBallOuter.clicked .subBall.linkedIn {
  transform: translate(-10em);
  -webkit-transform: translate(-10em);
  -moz-transform: translate(-10em);
  -ms-transform: translate(-10em);
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
.roundedBallOuter.clicked .subBall.facebook {
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-10em) rotate(-45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-10em) rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-10em) rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-10em) rotate(-45deg);
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
.roundedBallOuter.clicked .subBall.twitter {
  transform: rotate(90deg) translate(-10em) rotate(-90deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg) translate(-10em) rotate(-90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(90deg) translate(-10em) rotate(-90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg) translate(-10em) rotate(-90deg);
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
.more {
  font-size: 20px;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}
.more>span {
  color: #0077ab;
  display: block;
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 25px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="roundedBallOuter">
  <div class="roundedBall">
    <span class="more"><span>Click</span> for more information</span>
  </div>
  <div class="linkedIn subBall"></div>
  <div class="facebook subBall"></div>
  <div class="twitter subBall"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I did this (to be honest I don't really agree with the pixel calculation), but it did what it had to do. Thank you all guys!

```css
    #restOfThings .subBall {
        position: absolute;
        transition: all 0.5s ease;
        z-index: 0;
        left: -webkit-calc(50% - 25px);
        left: -moz-calc(50% - 25px);
        left: calc(50% - 25px);
        top: -webkit-calc(50% - 25px);
        top: -moz-calc(50% - 25px);
        top: calc(50% - 25px);
    }
```